# How to get success message after file upload in a html with tornado in the back end?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tornado

HI all here i am submitting a form/ uploading a form i want to display that file has been successfully uploaded on the same page can anybody help me in how to complete the task after the uploading the file i go to the upload url but it is  redirecting to the same html BUT i want to print a notification stating that the form has been submitted how can i achieve this

```
import tornado.httpserver, tornado.ioloop, tornado.options, tornado.web, os.path, random, string
from tornado.options import define, options

define("port", default=8888, help="run on the given port", type=int)

class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
            (r"/", IndexHandler),
            (r"/upload", UploadHandler)
                    ]
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers)

class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("upload_form.html",message=None)

class UploadHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        file1 = self.request.files['file1'][0]
        original_fname = file1['filename']
        extension = os.path.splitext(original_fname)[1]
        fname = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for x in range(6))
        final_filename= fname+extension
        output_file = open("uploads/" + final_filename, 'w')
        output_file.write(file1['body'])
        msg = "{} print in the same page".format(
        self.get_body_argument("file1",""))
        self.render("upload_form.html", message=msg)    
        #self.write("file" + final_filename + " is uploaded")

def main():
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(Application())
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

 if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and the HTML page is

```
enter code here
<html>
<body>
<p><h1>Tornado Upload App</h1></p>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload" method="post">
File: <input type="file" id="file1" />
<br />
<br />
<input  type="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
<div id="form">
 {% if message is not None %}
 <p>{{ message }}</p>
  {% end %}
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```